# How to convert a json object into user profile interface in Ionic + angular

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I'm using a method in ionic to retrieve specific a user record from firebase using user uid so that I can edit the user profile. I have created an interface of user and method is working fine is retrieve the user in object formate but I want to convert retrieve record to User Object/Interface. I got

```
[{
    "dob":"2004-07-14",
    "email":"mona@gmail.com",
    "firstName":"mona",
    "gender":"f",
    "lastName":"mona",
    "uid":"KiaLuMJuDmTBBAVQpRgHgR2"
}]
```

through console log on user record. So that I can access user.name inside the template. I'm new to Ionic.**I cant access user.firstName.** Is there anyway and other solution to access record in a template to do this? 
Thanks!

**User interface**

```
 export interface User{
        firstName: string;
        lastName: string;
        email: string;
        gender : string;
        dob : any
    }
```

**Method code**

```
   getUserProfile(){
       this.db.list('/profiles', ref => ref.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(this.id)).valueChanges().take(1)
        .subscribe(item  => {
            this.user = JSON.stringify(item);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
        },
        err => console.log("error in retrieving user from profile : "+err),
        () => console.log("user profile"));
      }
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your post but:
If I understand when you log `JSON.stringify(item)` you get an array with an object. But your interface is not an array. Maybe you should try `this.user = JSON.stringify(item)[0]`. What do you have in the console if you log `this.user` ?

Comment: Thanks Proustibat for response, on console, `console.log("User information: "+this.user)` I got User information : [object Object], I need to cast or convert list object to user object